# How to change password on RAR archive w/o modifying arch. files attributes (modified/created)?

Tags: windows, rar, winrar, file-attributes

How do I change the password of an .RAR archive, without changing the date/time attributes of the files in the archive?  Unfortunately you can't directly change the password of the archive with WinRAR, you have to extract the files, and then make a new archive with the new password.  So the created/modified attributes of the files in the archive get changed.  I know you can manually change the attributes of a file with available utilities - but there are hundreds of files in the archive, each with unique attributes, so it would take a very long time to "fix" each file before re-archiving it.

I'm using WinRAR 3.51, the last free version. Windows XP Pro SP3.

---

Update:  I don't care if the output is a .RAR file or a ZIP file

IZArc4.1 will convert the RAR to a ZIP, and it keeps the dates. The problem is it compresses the file - there isn't a "store" option, and setting the default to store in the main configuration doesn't effect conversions.  The RAR contains uncompressed files.

None of these other archiving programs will even do a conversion.  A couple claim to, or try to, but the errors returned indicate a very lousy application. So far I've tried PeaZip, 7-Zip, FilZip, TugZip, SimplyZipSE, QuickZip, and WinShrink (from downloads.cnet.com).

WinRAR gives the error "skipping encryped archive" when I try the conversion.  It asks for the password first, and I know it's right, as I opened the archive, and I can read/view all the files in it.  It works on non-encrypted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by converting the RAR archive to a TAR archive with IZArc, and then converting the TAR archive to an RAR archive with WinRAR (Tools-Convert-Compression for options). This preserved the date/time attributes, got past the problem that WinRAR won't convert a password protected archive (even though I know the password.)

Answer (score 0):

[PeaZip](http://www.peazip.org/) in its current version (6.6.1) now works fine - [changes only the password](http://www.peazip.org/change-password.html#change_password), while *keeps the original attributes of zipped files unchanged.*