# Need software to convert RAR to ZIP ("store" mode - no compression) * Extract->re-archive changes date/time attributes

Tags: windows, zip, archiving, rar, file-attributes

I have tried all of the following applications (download.cnet.com - the free ones), and none of them will convert an RAR archive to a ZIP, without compressing the files ("store" mode). 7-ZIP would be fine, too. [The RAR is a "solid" archive with password (I know it), files "stored" - no compression, used WinRAR 3.5.1]

```
 PeaZip, 7-Zip, FilZip, TugZip, SimplyZipSE, QuickZip, WinShrink.
```

(A couple of the apps let you try, but the program gives an error - indicating how bad the software is. (Like "unknown header #  #.")  None of these apps will do the conversion at all.

IZArc 4.1 comes the closest. It will convert an RAR to a ZIP, but it compresses the zip. There is a general preference setting to "store" - but it doesn't effect conversions.

I don't want to extract the RAR files and re-archive them because I need to preserve the modified/created file attributes.  IZArc preserves them, but it compresses the files.

WinRAR has the option to convert archives, but I get the error "skipping encryped archive" when I try to convert it.  It asks for the password first, and I know it's right because that password opens the archive, and I can read/view all the files in the archive.

Comment: Which OS are you using to do the conversion?

Comment: Windows XP Pro SP3.

Comment: So, what's the problem with 7-Zip? I'm sure it can extract rar files and also store the files again without compression.

Comment: The files can't be extracted first - read the problem description. If the files are extracted then the date/time attributes get changed.

Comment: @Larry78: Most good file compressing solutions (7-zip included) include a switch to preserve the original attributes while decompressing.

Comment: I just tested 7-zip - it obliterates the creation time. My RAR has both the modified and created times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by converting the RAR archive to a TAR archive with IZArc, and then converting the TAR archive to ZIP archive with WinRAR (Tools-Convert-Compression options-ZIP & "store"). This preserved the date/time attributes, and the ZIP is non-compressed( "store"), and got past the problem that WinRAR won't convert a password protected archive (I know the password.)

Answer (score 1):

Wait, you need to *convert* the archive formats? And you want to do this without decompressing first? Not going to happen. All programs that "convert" between archive types decompress and then recompress into the target archive format.

Comment: Well, I gave you one example in the description that DOES convert RAR to ZIP.  Download it and try it yourself.  When did I say anything about not decompressing it first?  If it was compressed (it isn't), then of course it would be decompressed first.  The probem is if you extract files from the archive to disk the date/time attributes of the files get changed. Again, IZArch does the conversion and doesn't modify the attributes. Try it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Larry: You said *"and none of them will convert an RAR archive to a ZIP, without compressing the files ("store" mode)."* I assumed you were trying to do this without decompressing the files. Why are the attributes to important?

Comment: Because they show when the original file was created and last modified.

Comment: @Larry: Again, what makes this so important? Why not extract, modify the attributes, and then recompress?

Comment: There are hundreds of files in the archive, each with unique attributes.  Why are you asking me questions - "what makes this so important? Why not "modify the attributes." If you don't have an answer to the posted question then please don't reply.

Comment: @Larry: *"crickets"* Do you see anyone else trying to help? How about *not* simply dismissing people's ideas before fully explaining the problem. If someone says *"I want to convert archives without changing file modification dates"* I think it's not out of the possible realm to ask *why* they want to do this.

Comment: Why I want to preserve modified/created attributes isn't anyone's business.  I do appreciate any help.

Comment: @Larry: Probably because you're trying to pass off the files as someone elses or not let people know they've been changed or tampered with. [See previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/157759/how-to-change-password-on-rar-archive-w-o-modifying-arch-files-attributes-modif).

Comment: To: Josh K - this is not a political discussion about Kagans Supreme Court confirmation hearing. GET A LIFE. When a file is changed the modified attribute is changed. By preserving the attributes in an archive it shows when the file was actually last modified. I said there are hundreds of files in the archive.